# Fragment and BroadcastReceiver freeze app after some seconds

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-fragmentactivity

Here is full code of the app which freezes (UI) after some seconds of work.

Is something dangerous here?

Thank you!

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    private Context _context;
    private View view;
    private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;

    public FragmentOne() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);
        setup();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context)
    {
        super.onAttach(context);
        _context = context;
    }

    private void setup()
    {
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i)
            {
                try
                { 
                    DLocation dLocation = (DLocation) i.getExtras().get("coordinates");

                    if (dLocation != null) {
                        Log.d("Первый фрагмент", "Применение параметров шир. сообщения к контролам окна");

                        TextView textLon = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textLon);
                        textLon.setText(dLocation.Longitude);

                        TextView textLat =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textLat);
                        textLat.setText(dLocation.Latitude);

                        TextView textTime =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textTime);
                        textTime.setText(dLocation.TimeOfRequest);

                        TextView textErrors = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textErrors);
                        textErrors.setText(dLocation.Errors);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {                        
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };

        _context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("location_update"));


    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();  

        if (broadcastReceiver != null) {
            _context.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your broadcast receiver is the culprit here.

Comment: @Umair perhaps yes... Any clue to optimize it?

Comment: Instead of BroadcastReceiver use a Interface to listen for location changes. BroadcastReceiver is and Component it should not be used just for callback purposes where and interface can work.

Comment: @AcademyofProgrammer what exactly is your broadcast receiver does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Root Cause

I think you are using a 3rd party library to detect location. The library is receiving the GPS coordinates at a very high rate. These coordinates are then received by your broadcast receiver. Your broadcast receiver is doing it's work on the UI thread. The reason why your app freezes is because the UI thread is doing work at very high rate.

#### Solution

The solution to your problem lies in Bound Service. You can find code examples in android developer docs [Bound Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html).

For use cases like a music player, where media is played in a background thread but duration of played music is shown on the UI, bound service can be useful. I hope this sets you in the right direction.